# Nstableview with custom tablecellview not displaying any data

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift2

Tableview is loading but not displaying any outlet from custom cell

```
class ViewController: NSViewController,NSTableViewDataSource,NSTableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //let color : CGColorRef = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0)
   self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor       

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {       

    let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("AppointmentCell", owner: self)  as! AppointmentCell!

    if tableColumn!.identifier == "Column" { 
        return cell
    }
    return cell  
}

func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}

 func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat
 {
    return 100        
}
}
class AppointmentCell: NSTableCellView {
    @IBOutlet weak var Start: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Increment: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var decrement: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var addNotes: NSButton!

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)    
        // Drawing code here.
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check if cell is existed.
After dequeue a cell view from tableview, you should set you content in cell view.
It usually occur in 
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?